# Diagram blocks overlapping

Tags: beamer, diagrams, flow-charts

I'm trying to add to a beamer presentation a diagram that I previously created in R, namely:

[image: Flowchart R]

I believe that the best option to do so is by adopting the Tkiz package, yet I'm having a hard time making it work.

I have no problem recreating the style of the block: for example, for the blue blocks I'm using

```
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
text width=3.5em, text badly centered, node distance=.5cm, inner sep=0pt]
```

and it works perfectly. What I am failing at is positioning the blocks properly. They overlap with each other no matter whether I use `right of = xxx` (the positioning option) or `right = of xxx`.

I apologise but this is the first time I am using Tkiz and I'm getting a bit lost.

Thanks for your help!

```
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=.5cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = .5cm, auto]
    % blocks
   \node [decision] (LR) {Literature Reviews};
   \node [block, right = of LR] (NR) {Narrative Reviews};
   \node [decision, right = of LR] (SR) {Systematic Review};
   \node [block, right = of SR] (VC) {Vote Counting};
   \node [decision, right = of SR] (MA) {Meta-Analysis};
   \node [block, right = of SR] (O) {Others};
   \node [block, right = of VC] (IVC) {Informal Vote Counting};
   \node [block, right = of VC] (FVC) {Formal Vote Counting};
   \node [block, right = of MA] (PB) {Publication Bias};
   \node [block, right = of MA] (MO) {Moderator Analysis};
   \node [block, right = of MO] (MRA) {Meta-Regression};
   \node [block, right = of MO] (CM) {Categorical Models};   
   \node [block, right = of MO] (CT) {Clustering Techniques};
    % lines
    \path [line] (LR) -- (NR);
    \path [line] (LR) -- (SR);
    \path [line] (SR) -- (VC);
    \path [line] (SR) -- (MA);
    \path [line] (SR) -- (O);   
    \path [line] (VC) -- (IVC);
    \path [line] (VC) -- (FVC);
    \path [line] (MA) -- (PB);
    \path [line] (MA) -- (MO);
    \path [line] (MO) -- (MRA);
    \path [line] (MO) -- (CM);
    \path [line] (MO) -- (CT);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Marco

Comment: you should turn your code snippet into a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: What if you increase the distances?

Comment: One of your previous questions received multiple answers, can you please go back and check if one of them solved your problem and if yes accept it?

Comment: I tried to have a look at similar Tkiz issues but all I could find are multilevel flowcharts and electrical diagrams but nothing of this sort

Comment: Note that `\tikzstyle` has long been deprecated: switch to `\tikzset` as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider for example that you have placed three different nodes `right=of SR`. In other words, those three nodes are in the exact same place. Use `above right` or `below right` where appropriate. You can fine tune positions by adding `xshift` and `yshift` (e.g. `xshift=3mm`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows}
\tikzset{
 decision/.style={diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt},
 block/.style={rectangle, draw, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
 line/.style={draw, -latex'}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = .6cm and .6cm, auto]
    % blocks
   \node [decision] (LR) {Literature Reviews};
   \node [block, above right = of LR] (NR) {Narrative Reviews};
   \node [decision,below right = of LR] (SR) {Systematic Review};
   \node [block, above right = of SR] (VC) {Vote Counting};
   \node [decision, right = of SR] (MA) {Meta-Analysis};
   \node [block, below right = of SR] (O) {Others};
   \node [block, above right = of VC] (IVC) {Informal Vote Counting};
   \node [block, right = of VC] (FVC) {Formal Vote Counting};
   \node [block, below right = of MA] (PB) {Publication Bias};
   \node [block, right = of MA] (MO) {Moderator Analysis};
   \node [block, above right = of MO] (MRA) {Meta-Regression};
   \node [block, right = of MO] (CM) {Categorical Models};   
   \node [block, below right = of MO] (CT) {Clustering Techniques};
    % lines
    \path [line] (LR) -- (NR);
    \path [line] (LR) -- (SR);
    \path [line] (SR) -- (VC);
    \path [line] (SR) -- (MA);
    \path [line] (SR) -- (O);   
    \path [line] (VC) -- (IVC);
    \path [line] (VC) -- (FVC);
    \path [line] (MA) -- (PB);
    \path [line] (MA) -- (MO);
    \path [line] (MO) -- (MRA);
    \path [line] (MO) -- (CM);
    \path [line] (MO) -- (CT);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tweaked it a bit using `xshift` and `yshift` as you suggested; I also reduced the font size and the node distance to make it better fit into a beamer presentation and now it looks great. Thank you so much for your help!